# Cannot access to shared folders

Tags: windows-8.1, network-shares, credentials

I try to access to shared folder on another Win8.1 (named `ahura`) machine from my PC. When I want to navigate to `\\ahura` I see the following prompt. While I enter username and password of an admin user of the remote machine correctly, it does not accept the credential. What is wrong with it?

[image]

Comment: did you try to access it through IP?

Comment: I will put it as answer, can you please mark it as answer

Comment: @Scorpion99 I think an answer should explain why using computer name does not work.

Comment: did you try to use nslookup in cmd?

Comment: @Scorpion99 How should I use it?

Comment: Go to run ---> cmd and type : nslookup ahura

Comment: @Scorpion99 `*** UnKnown can't find AHURA: Non-existent domain` Are you sure nslookup works with computer names? It even send same error for my current PC's name.

Comment: @Scorpion99 Please return your answer. For now, I will mark it as answer.

Answer (score 0):

You might have a problem with DNS , so simply try to access it through IP.